# Counting words in a apropos command

Tags: linux, unix

I have this command `apropos -l apple`. I want to count the word "apple" from the output of the command. I am a beginner in UNIX commands, and have an idea that I have to use `grep` or `wc`, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Piping them together `apropos -l apple | grep apple | wc -l` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apropos -l apple | grep -io apple
```

There are many options within grep that can help you meet your objective and the above is just an example.

Take the output of apropos -l and then pipe through to grep. With grep, we search for all "apple" entries with -i to show any case combinations. We then finally output the generated list through to wc -l to count the lines and therefore the entries,